# 24GB tar.gz Decompress using sharpziplib

Tags: c#, .net, sharpziplib

I have a current process to extract tar.gz but the current process can not handle over 4gb... I was wondering what I am doing wrong to cause me to get a error using the sharpzip lib It says that parameter length can not be less that Zero.... All of the commented out code is the current process

Please see the below code and give me direction

```
public static void ExtractTarGZFiles(string strExtractionPath, string strInboundFolder)
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        string strFile = Path.GetFullPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InboundFolderPath"].ToString());
        if (mblnRunForFile)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo ioInfo = new FileInfo(mstrFilename);
            strFile = ioInfo.DirectoryName;
            files.Add(ioInfo.Name);

        }
        else
        {
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InboundFolderPath"], "*.gz").ToList();
        }

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            try
            {
            //string stFilePath = file;
            //string testingthisdamnthing = strInboundFolder + mstrFilename;
            //FileStream xstream = new FileStream(stFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            //xstream.Close();
            //string strTemp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExtractTempFolderPath"];
            //TarArchive objTA = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(new GZipStream(new FileStream(stFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), CompressionMode.Decompress));
            //objTA.ProgressMessageEvent += ExtractTarNotifier;
             //objTA.ExtractContents(strTemp);



            //DirectoryInfo dirtemp = new DirectoryInfo(strTemp);
            DirectoryInfo dirExtract = new DirectoryInfo(strExtractionPath);

            Stream inStream = File.OpenRead(stFilePath);
            Stream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(inStream);

            TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gzipStream);
            tarArchive.ExtractContents(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExtractFolderPath"]);
            tarArchive.Close();

            gzipStream.Close();
            inStream.Close();
            //while (IsFileExistsinTempPath(dirtemp, dirExtract))
            //{
            //    //Do nothing
            //}
            //CopyFilesFromTempToExtract(dirtemp, dirExtract);
            //objTA.Close();
            //Logger.Write(" Tar.Gz files Decompressed Successfully");
            MonthLog.Log("Tar.Gz files Decompressed Successfully", "Month", 3, 2, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, mstrFilename);
            System.IO.File.Copy(stFilePath, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArchiveFolderPath"] + new FileInfo(stFilePath).Name, true);
            File.Delete(stFilePath);
            //Logger.Write(" Tar.GZ files Moved to Archive Folder");
            MonthlyGreenPackageLog.Log("Tar.Gz files Moved to Archive Folder", "Month", 3, 2, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information, mstrFilename);

            }
                catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
                {
                    //go to next file
                    //Logger.Write("Unable to open compressed file");
                    MonthLog.Log("Unable to open compressed file", "Month", 1, 1, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, mstrFilename);
                    Email objEmail1 = new Email();
                    objEmail1.IsBodyHTML = true;
                    objEmail1.FromAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromAddress"];
                    string[] strToAddresses = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExceptionAddress"].Split(',');
                    objEmail1.SetToAddress(strToAddresses);
                    objEmail1.Subject = "The Month  File  " + mstrFilename + " Failed to Decompress ";
                    objEmail1.Body = " Exception " + ex.Message + " occured while decompressing file";
                    //objEmail.AddAttachment("Exception occured while processingfiles");
                    objEmail1.SendEmail();
                    //Logger.Write("Sent a mail to all the Address");
                    throw ex;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Logger.Write("Exception " + ex.Message + " occured while decompressing file");
                    MonthlyGreenPackageLog.Log("Exception " + ex.Message + " occured while decompressing file", "Monthl", 1, 1, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, mstrFilename);
                    Email objEmail = new Email();
                    objEmail.IsBodyHTML = true;
                    objEmail.FromAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromAddress"];
                    string[] strToAddresses = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExceptionAddress"].Split(',');
                    objEmail.SetToAddress(strToAddresses);
                    objEmail.Subject = "The tar.gz Month File  " + mstrFilename + " Failed to Decompress ";
                    objEmail.Body = " Exception " + ex.Message + " occured while decompressing file";
                    //objEmail.AddAttachment("Exception occured while processing ADX files");
                    objEmail.SendEmail();
                    //Logger.Write("Sent a mail to all the Address");
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you compile it as x86 or x64?

Comment: Then you will need to figure out how to break up your file into 4GB chunks, you need 64 bit to play with more.

Comment: Not possible, It is sent to us VIA FTP....

Comment: So My only real option is to make it a 64 application and get it on a 64bit system. Do I use what I currently have in production? or what is my best option?

Comment: @user2133071 correct, 64 bit OS and app with the zip library compiled as 64bit should do. Chances are some of the descriptor fields are 64 bit and one of them has its 31st bit=1, so when interpreted as int32 it becomes negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three potential solutions for you, but I can't tell you whether any of them will actually work.

1. Use the [Unzip from Stream](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#wiki-anchorUnpackZIS) example to stream it through memory so you never need to load the whole thing (which is why it fails now).
2. Switch to using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), which might have more options for handling large files on an x86 machine.
3. Find a regular unzipper application which can be scripted or that can monitor a directory, and unzip it before it gets to your application.

Comment: I don't think it's a memory issue, chances are some of the descriptor fields are 64 bit and one of them has its 31st bit=1, so when interpreted as int32 it becomes negative

Comment: Have you used the Command Line for 7zip? How does that work with the x command.?

Comment: @user2133071 - I haven't myself, but [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) has some good detail

Answer (score 0):

If you have your application as x86, then you can only have 4GB of memory per process. Compile it as x64 to use more resources.

Comment: Doesn't help if the machine isn't x64 also.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the ZipLibrary you're using.  You need to compile the application as an x64 program and run it on a 64 bit environment.

```
    // To permit the zip to be unpacked by built-in extractor in WinXP and Server2003, WinZip 8, Java, and other older code,
    // you need to do one of the following: Specify UseZip64.Off, or set the Size.
    // If the file may be bigger than 4GB, or you do not need WinXP built-in compatibility, you do not need either,
    // but the zip will be in Zip64 format which not all utilities can understand.
```